# Typehint the type of a collection and the collection itself

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting

Say I want to collect and iterable into another type in the collect method:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Collection
from dataclasses import dataclass
T = TypeVar("T")

@dataclass
class Example(Generic[T]):
    data: list[T]
    
    def collect(self, collector: type[Collection]) -> Collection[T]:
        return collector(self.data)
```

If implemented like that, the typehinting information of which collector is used is lost:

```py
# result should type-hint 'set[int]'
# but instead shows 'Collection[int]'
# The collector type is lost..
result = Example([1, 2]).collect(set)
```

How can I keep both the type of collection and the type of what is held by the collection, while keeping it all generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `type[Collection]`, use `Callable` to specify the signature and take advantage of how the return type can be inferred:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=2420a6e37db925310a60186878db315f), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBAxmA28CmMAuBLMA7AzgOgEMAjGKdCABzBFSgGEDFjkBYAKFEigBMDUCY8AjhxIcZStVq9%2Bg4TnadoqAJ4V0WAOYSqNKAHEkWJCHQwANFAAqapADUCIduytQAvNdsOQACgDkVn4AlOx07p4U9o7%2BdMHObAACMgJCIuxyIlAAogAeBJTIPobGpjAA2lYAukEAXOxQDTx8BDVQ8Og4qBWV9Y29DdxIwLAIyGg%2BovDAlnCIKKjUrQxMRMhlZe2d3ZWWdNVQALQAfPR1bI0XUCBIqACuIFgjc2jUE0hTeMkhbPFIeQVIcK5fIUQplACMlgATNV4tcAG5IRgAfVUkR8fxByDwszGqDeqCCQUuDQAxFAIGoVFAAGRQCgqUyaAAWtDcJ1EXQ0qB6bARSPgqNsGP%2BoKQONG8x8dzFRMu5MpDNp9MZ6BZbJOMrW3MseD1vP5KLRSBFWPFuKlm0JxPlFKpyoZTNZ7hOVrK3INSERRuFmIBEue%2BOBALlZLtSrpjrVzvZ2VF2qwPPYQA))</sub>

```py
@dataclass
class Example(Generic[T]):
    data: list[T]
    
    def collect(self, collector: Callable[[list[T]], C]) -> C:
        return collector(self.data)
```

```py
example = Example([1, 2])

reveal_type(example.collect(set))       # mypy & pyright => set[int]
reveal_type(example.collect(tuple))     # mypy & pyright => tuple[int, ...]
reveal_type(example.collect(list))      # mypy & pyright => list[int]
reveal_type(example.collect(Example))   # mypy & pyright => Example[int]
```

This also allows functions to be passed as `collector`, but this minor detail should not make a difference, since functions and classes are both `Callable`:

```py
reveal_type(example.collect(lambda elements: list(elements)))
# mypy & pyright => list[int]
```

This works because `set`, `tuple`, `list` and `Example` are all assignable to `Callable[[list[int]], C]`. [From the `typeshed` library](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi):

```py
class set(MutableSet[_T]):
    @overload
    def __init__(self) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self, __iterable: Iterable[_T]) -> None: ...
```

The second overload says that a `set[_T]` may be constructed by passing an `Iterable[_T]` to the class. `list[int]` is assignable to `Iterable[_T]`, so type checkers infer `_T` as `int` and `C` as `set[int]`. The same applies to other callables I mentioned above.

Another solution is to define `__iter__()` and let `set()` *et al.* be called directly, if `collect()` doesn't do anything further than passing `.data`:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=c9903f9ea1a16b71aeecb1b84bf58a4d), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBAxmA28CmMAuBLMA7AzgOgEMAjGKdCABzBFSgElUkQDVqBYAKFEigBMWCMeARw4kOMpWq1%2BqQcNGdu0VAE8K6LAHNJVGlADiSLE3QwANFAAq6pADUCITpytQAvNdsOQACgDkVn4AlJwAwu6eFPaO-qHBzhwAArLyIjicQmlQAKIAHgSUyD5GJiBmANpWALpBAFycUI18ArVQ8Og4qJVVDU29jbxIwFAA%2BiPojCBjPmLwwEFQALQAfPSTLNTd9RxNu1Cq6EjwvFDKULPAeCkJnEj5hUgReQUUReUAjJYATDUJIEgANyQBHgIzUURmSFQPjuL2QQQWTQAxFAIOpVFAAGRQCiqMpaAAWtDcqzEXU0qB6HH%2BQJBYNsPlQAFdXkgYfdWQjGii0bisTi8ehCcTVszWeUKZY8NKqTTgaDwWz2p12XCkFzuaj0fzcfiie5VsryVhKZwgA))</sub>

```py
@dataclass
class Example(Generic[T]):
    data: list[T]
    
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:  # Or Generator[T, None, None]
        yield from self.data
```

```py
example = Example([1, 2])

reveal_type(set(example))    # mypy & pyright => set[int]
reveal_type(tuple(example))  # mypy & pyright => tuple[int, ...]
reveal_type(list(example))   # mypy & pyright => list[int]
```

`Example(example)` won't work since `Example`'s `__init__()` expects a `list`, not an `Iterator`; you would need `Example(list(example))`.

Comment: Ah Nice! Interestingly this does not work if you rely on a default argument for the collect method. Thanks!

Comment: @IzaakCornelis If you want a default argument, you need to also specify the type arguments: `def collect(self, collector: Callable[[list[T]], C] = list[T]) -> C:`.

Comment: This [works with Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBAxmA28CmMAuBLMA7AzgOgEMAjGKdCABzBFSgGEDFjkBYAKFEigBMDUCY8AjhxIcZStVq9%2Bg4TnadoqAJ4V0WAOYSqNKAHEkWJCHQwANFAAqapADUCIduytQAvNdsOQACgDkVn4AlOx07p4U9o7%2BdMHObAACMgJCIuxyIlAAogAeBJTIPobGpjAA2lYAukEAXOxQDTx8BDVQ8Og4qBWV9Y29DdxIwLAIyGg%2BovDAlnCIKKjUrQxMRMhlZe2d3ZWWdJXhm11VQVAAtAB89HVsjbdQIEioAK4gWCNzaNQTSFN4ySFseJIPIFJDhXL5CiFMoARksACZqvEHgA3JCMAD6qkiPmBkOQeFmY1QPiCJzutwAxFAKCpTJoABa0NyXQ5lDSoHpsIA) but not Mypy. I think this is a bug.

Comment: ...It's not. According to the maintainers, `list` is inferred as `list[Unknown]` in such a context.